# AVMetadataFaceObject Yaw Angle Reversed / Opposite Depending on Device Model

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I'm implementing a face detection feature using AVFoundation's AVMetadataFaceObject and the AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate. I am using the front camera to detect the yaw angle, to see how far the user is turning their head. When looking at the angles on an iPhone X, turning right is 270.0 degrees or 315.0 degrees while turning left is 45.0 degrees or 90.0 degrees. When looking at the angles on an iPhone 8, turning right is 45.0 degrees or 90.0 degrees while turning left is 270.0 degrees or 315.0 degrees. The yaw angles are opposites. The same problem was posed here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/113542 without a response.

This is my first time testing it on a device other than iPhone X.

```
// I add the queue here...
        if captureSession.canAddOutput(metadataOutput) {
            captureSession.addOutput(metadataOutput)
            metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: metaQueue)
            metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [.face]
        }

func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput,
                        didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject],
                        from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        let metadataObjects = metadataObjects as? [AVMetadataFaceObject]
        for metadataObject in metadataObjects! {
// turnAngle is different across devices
        let turnAngle = Double(metadataObject.yawAngle)
        }
    }
```

I expect the output to be consistent across devices in that turning right should always produce a yaw angle of x, while turning left should always produce a yaw angle of y. I'm thinking perhaps this has something to do with the device orientation, but really not sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found if device has Multisession support then that opposite yaw angle happened.
So you can check the device using

AVCaptureMultiCamSession.isMultiCamSupported

If AVCaptureMultiCamSession.isMultiCamSupported == true then it is iPhone XS XR XS Max ... and later
else it is from iPhone X earlier